# Django ORM to find if a string contains column value

Tags: django, django-orm

I'd like to know how to write ORM code of the following SQL:

```
select * from t1 where 'ABCDEFG' LIKE CONCAT('%',column1,'%');
```

It seems that Django supports only the following code:

```
XYZ.objects.filter(column1__contains='ABCDEFG')
```

What I want is something like that:

```
XYZ.objects.filter('ABCDEFG'__contains=column1)
```

I'd like to know the correct way of Python/Django.

Thank you.

Comment: what will be expected result of SQL query?

Answer (score 3):

```
XYZ.objects\
    .annotate(querystring=Value('ABCDEFG', output_field=CharField()))\
    .filter(querystring__icontains=F('column1'))
```

My team mate found this one. It works for me.
Under the hood it gives the same SQL as topic starter mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
XYZ.objects.filter(Q(('{}__contains'.format("ABCDEFG"), "column1")))
```

Comment: `column1` is not a string value but the field of database. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can pass the column name as a string. `"column1"`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: For me this solution does not work. Cannot resolve keyword 'ABCDEFG' into field. Choices are: ....